# the value of accuracy and loss change by the order of the training

Tags: machine-learning, python, accuracy, tensorflow, keras

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13wMNCXxKs_uqFVzuJqE2zxhsxWK8Ya4k?usp=sharing

Hello guys

I’m having a hard time trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I used 4 pretrained models from huggingface and tokenized each model with same data.

Then I’m trying to ensemble the predict values from 4 models.

The problem is that the value of accuracy and loss change by the order of the training.

For example,

model1 train / 0.98

model2 train / 0.3

model3 train / 0.98

model4 train / 0.98

Or

model2 train / 0.98

model1 train / 0.3

model3 train / 0.98

model4 train / 0.98

When training model1 first, I get 0.98 for the accuracy. After that, training model2 shows 0.3 accuracy.

But if I train model2 first, I get 0.98 for the accuracy and 0.3 accuracy for training model1.

I can't understand why the accuracy value changes just because I have changed the order of the model although they are the same training models.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly does it mean that you train them "in order"? Does the ordering in any way affect the data you use for each model? Have you checked that you definitely change the order of the models?

Comment: If you’re using the same prng among the models, the state of the generator will change after each use, so all parts of the model training process that use prng will change.

Comment: **IF** the model has fully converged to the optimal solution, this should not happen. So maybe let the optimization work harder?